# How to update a hierarchyid column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table called `items` which has a parent/child relation that I am converting to a hierarchyid.

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/lesson-1-converting-a-table-to-a-hierarchical-structure?view=sql-server-2017) tutorial to do so.

All the steps of the tutorial works, except the final update statement.

I get the error message:

> Implicit conversion from data type hierarchyid to nvarchar(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

But this makes no sense.  The field I am updating is a hierarchyid, not an nvarchar(nax). So I don't see where an nvarchar(max) field is involved.

```
drop table #children
CREATE TABLE #Children   
   (  
    ID int,  
    TenantId int,
    ParentID int,
    Num int  
);  
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX tmpind ON #Children(TenantId, ParentID, ID);  
GO

INSERT #Children (ID,  TenantId,ParentID, Num)  
SELECT ID, TenantId, ParentID, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TenantId, ParentID ORDER BY ParentId)   
FROM Items  
GO 

SELECT * FROM #Children ORDER BY TenantId, ParentID, Num  
GO


WITH paths(path, ID, ParentId, TenantId)   
AS (  
-- This section provides the value for the root of the hierarchy  
SELECT hierarchyid::GetRoot() AS OrgNode, ID, ParentId, TenantId   
FROM #Children AS C   
WHERE ParentId IS NULL   

UNION ALL   
-- This section provides values for all nodes except the root  
SELECT   
CAST(p.path.ToString() + CAST(C.Num AS varchar(30)) + '/' AS hierarchyid),   
C.ID , C.ParentId, C.TenantId 
FROM #Children AS C   
JOIN paths AS p   
   ON C.ParentID = P.ID   
)
-- This select statement runs just fine and shows expected data.
--Select i.Id as ItemId, p.path, p.path.ToString() as LogicalNode, p.Id, p.ParentId, p.TenantId from Paths P
--join Items I on p.Id = i.Id
--order by P.TenantId, P.path

--Note that I have tried using the convert function, but it still fails with the same error message.
UPDATE I Set OrgNode = Convert(hierarchyid, P.path)
FROM Items I    
JOIN Paths AS P   
   ON I.ID = P.ID  
GO
```

**EDIT**
Strangely, this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=48fb52634a13ffba3dae3d0c2890e256) works.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like column `OrgNode` is not of type `hierachyid`. You could use `ToString()`

```
UPDATE I Set OrgNode = P.path.ToString()
FROM Items I    
JOIN Paths AS P   
   ON I.ID = P.ID
```

or alter table `Items` and change column type.

Comment: I tried using ToString() as above, but it gives the same error message.  And Items.OrgNode IS of type hierarchyId, as you can see from the screenshot I added. That is why it is so strange to get that error message.

Comment: @Greg0 Please post reproducible code on http://dbfiddle.uk with single record of data.

Comment: Done, but strangely, it is working fine there. See link above.

Comment: @Greg0 I suggest then to install newest Cumulative Update for your SQL Server version.

Comment: I just realized what happened, - there is a trigger on this table that is interfering with the process.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you solved your problem, but I would suggest saving the conversion to hierarchyid to the end. Like this:

```
WITH paths(path, ID, ParentId, TenantId)   
AS (  
-- This section provides the value for the root of the hierarchy  
SELECT cast('/' as varchar(max)) AS OrgNode, ID, ParentId, TenantId   
FROM #Children AS C   
WHERE ParentId IS NULL   

UNION ALL   
-- This section provides values for all nodes except the root  
SELECT   
CAST(concat(p.path.ToString(), C.Num, '/') AS varchar(max)),   
C.ID , C.ParentId, C.TenantId 
FROM #Children AS C   
JOIN paths AS p   
   ON C.ParentID = P.ID   
)
-- This select statement runs just fine and shows expected data.
--Select i.Id as ItemId, p.path, p.path.ToString() as LogicalNode, p.Id, p.ParentId, p.TenantId from Paths P
--join Items I on p.Id = i.Id
--order by P.TenantId, P.path

--Note that I have tried using the convert function, but it still fails with the same error message.
UPDATE I Set OrgNode = Convert(hierarchyid, P.path)
FROM Items I    
JOIN Paths AS P   
   ON I.ID = P.ID  
GO
```

Note, I also changed the `+` style of concatenation for the `concat()` function so you don't have to mess around with converting `C.Num` to a varchar.